# How to get both value and text from html select using thymeleaf

Tags: java, thymeleaf

Given the following POJO which only has two fields:

Entity:

- id
- name

I have a form with the following select:

```
<select required="required" name="name" id="myId">
    <option th:disabled="disabled" selected="true" value="">Choose Value</option>
    <option th:each="element : ${elements}"
            th:value="${element.id}"
            th:text="${element.name}">
    </option>
</select>
```

I'm trying to populate the entity fields so the id field is populated through the th:value (which would be the value of the selected element.id) and the name field is populated through the th:text (which would be the value of the selected element.name).

As I understand (and what I achieved) is that I only can populate one field using html select tag (the one I set in name's select tag). Any idea about how can I get both th:text and th:value values mapped in my entity using thymeleaf?

Comment: Check out this tutorial: https://spring.io/guides/gs/handling-form-submission/

Comment: I followed this tutorial at my beginning. The thing is that you can notice he uses two input fields, now I want to get both values just with one select element.

Answer (score 1):

There're several ways to do that :--

**1.)** After receiving the `value` on your controller, you could always `perform a select query from your Database based on the value received on your controller`, to get the text-value value.

**2.)** You could use a `hidden html` element along with your `html-option` and then use javascript to submit your form and get both of the values.

Answer (score 0):

As far as standard procedures concerned you cannot get both values at the same time. You can however submit the value field as a concatenated version of both values. You can achieve that as follows:

```
<option th:each="element : ${elements}"
        th:value="${element.id} + '~' + ${element.name}"
        th:text="${element.name}">
</option>
```